# Java: ООП, Конструкторы

Tags: java, ооп, объекты, конструктор, java-hashmap

Не знаю как точно сформулировать вопрос в гугл, и где искать ответ.
Есть класс `Nclass` и есть HashMap (вне этого класса) в котором ключ это поле `name` класса Nclass, а значение сам экземпляр класса. 
Так вот, как в конструкторе класса при инициализации всех полей, добавить этот новоиспеченный экземпляр в этот хешмэп? что бы не делать это каждый раз вручную. 
Как правильно сделать конструктор

```
public Nclass(тратата) {
    ...
    ...
    hashMap.put(name, себя же);
}
```

Comment: Зачем такие трудности? Разве нельзя сделать что-то вроде: `Nclass o = new Nclass(...); hashMap.put(o.getName(), o);`

Comment: Я думаю можно сделать это и через конструктор, как хочет автор: `hashMap.put(name, this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать как Вы хотите, то код будет следующим:

```
public class(String name) {
    hashMap.put(name, this);
}
```

Но, делать так я бы крайне не советовал. Потому что получиться следующая ситуация: `hashMap` создаете в одном месте (вне этого класса), а используете в другом (вам еще нужно будет получить доступ к `hashMap`). Поэтому, я думаю, лучше поступить следующим образом:

```
Map<...> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
//...
Nclass o = new Nclass();
hashMap.put(o.getName(), o);
//...
```

Comment: Согласен, так будет лучше всего. Действительно, доступ к hashMap надо еще получить, и скорее всего его в том же конструкторе и придется передавать.